# Ride Reminders Uber Api got JSON error

Tags: uber-api

Hello I am trying implement Ride Reminder Uber API in my project but I got error response like:

Reference URL:

```
https://developer.uber.com/docs/v1-reminders-post
```

JSON Error Response:

```
{
"message": "Unable to parse JSON in request body.",
"code": "invalid_json"
}
```

URL

```
https://api.uber.com/v1/reminders
```

Headers:

```
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Token vzOv0AaaZVRaV1FiZLt9SPU2ZgIrBgQ6uZy6j4Gr
```

Post Params:

```
reminder_time:1451496600(Unix UTC timestamp of when the reminder will occur.)
phone_number: +91xxxxxxxxxx(India's number)
server_token: vzOv0AaaZVRaV1FiZLt9SPU2ZgIrBgQ6uZy6j4Gr
event: {
         "time": "1451498400",
         "longitude": "72.5290",
         "latitude": "23.0384",
         "location": "Vastrapurlake",
         "name": "Test"
      }
```

More detail check PostMan Screen shots:

Post Params:[Click here](http://prntscr.com/9ktlr8)
Header Params:[Click here](http://prntscr.com/9ktm0h)

Can you please help me out, Thanks In Advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Content-Type and token are valid dont change anything there.

Just convert your params in json dont forgot to use double quote.

You have to pass these data as json format in postman.

```
{"reminder_time":"1451649600",
"phone_number": "+91<YOUR-MOBILE-NUMBER>",
"server_token": "vzOv0AaaZVRaV1FiZLt9SPU2ZgIrBgQ6uZy6j4Gr",
"event": {
         "time": "1451649600",
         "longitude": "72.5290",
         "latitude": "23.0384",
         "location": "Vastrapurlake",
         "name": "Test"
      }}
```

[image]